# Export DOM Document as XML with userData as Attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces

I am handling a `Document` object with data, some of the nodes have userData associated to them (using `setUserData(<key>, <value>, <handler>)`). I want to save a copy of the Document to XML, with exporting the userData values as attributes.

**Transformer**

This is the way I know to output XML:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(<Document>);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But there I cannot find a way to hook in at a method where both the old and the new Node objects exist – the only place I could find while digging into `Transformer` was a class `DOM2TO` that translates the nodes into eg. SAX calls to `startElement(...)`, but I cannot change anything here without copyPasting the whole code around it.

**UserDataHandler**

My second approach was to use a UserDataHandler to attach to the Node together with the userData. That handler has to provide a method `handle(short operation, String key, Object data, Node src, Node dst)` that is called eg. when the Node is cloned. So it would be possible to write a UserDataHandler that checks the `src` Node for userData and add it as an Attribute to `dst` and then simply cloning the Document before writing the XML from the clone. **Unfortunately**, `handle(...)`is getting called at a stage when the `dst` Node clone is not finished: When `src` has attributes, `dst` will point to the same `AttributeMap` instance at that time. Thus, the whole process is worthless, because the added attributes would also get added to the original Document, and I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved – I have to user a UserDataHandler that works at `NODE_IMPORTED`: Then the `handle(...)` method is called with a completely cloned `dst` node.

This is not a nice solution though, as cloning (hrm, *importing*) the Document doubles the needed space.